# Attribute form defaults: How to take over the settings directly when duplicating the layer (and not afterwards by copy-paste-styles)

Tags: layers, duplication, attribute-form

I have a point-shapefile-layer with attribute form defaults for some fields, QGIS 3.16 (see image, red marks). If I now duplicate the layer (by exporting or by duplicating) these attribute form settings are not taken over in the new layer and the fields remain empty. Of course I can reassign the fields by copy-and-paste-styles afterwards. 
But is there any option (by general settings, or ...) to take over the attribute form defaults when creating the new layer and not to reassign them afterwards?

[[image]][

Comment: Have you tried to copy & paste the style of the original layer?

Comment: Yes, that works of course. But as I tried to explain, I would like to take over the attribute form settings **without** style-copy-paste afterwards. --> No option?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Oh, sorry. QGIS on Win10.